# Point in time restore MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-5.6

I want to perform a point in time restore on MySQL.

I want to change log_bin value and ensure that log files are created.

I am following [this article](http://blog.bytetouch.com/system-administration/mysql-backup-and-point-in-time-recovery-with-binary-logs/) and am working on a Windows platform.

Log files are not created in the directory I specified? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Location on Windows for my.ini `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini`